# Get exit code from docker entrypoint command

Tags: bash, docker

I have a docker container that runs a script via the entrypoint directive. The container closes after the entrypoint script is finished. I need to get the exit code from the script in order to do some logging if the script fails. Right now I'm thinking of something like this

```
docker run container/myContainer:latest

if [ $? != 0 ];
then
    do some stuff
fi
```

Is this proper way to achieve this? Specifically, will this be the exit code of docker run or of my entrypoint script?

Comment: Yes the `$?`  is the exit status of the last command executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `docker container run` exit code is the exit code from your entrypoint/cmd:

```
$ docker container run busybox /bin/sh -c "exit 5"

$ echo $?
5
```

You may also inspect the state of an exited container:

```
$ docker container inspect --format '{{.State.ExitCode}}' \
    $(docker container ls -lq)
5
```

Comment: what if the entrypoint contains a pipeline? Is it possible to use "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"?

Comment: @tuxErrante Docker and the Linux kernel doesn't know what a pipeline is, that's a shell thing. If the shell exits with a non-zero, docker will accept that. So you need your shell to handle pipeline failures and pass the appropriate response to docker as an exit code.

Comment: Actually I resolved using SHELL bash before the entrypoint and then exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}

Answer (score 3):

Checking the value of $? is not needed if you just want to act upon the exit status of the previous command.

```
if docker run container/myContainer:latest; then
  do_stuff
fi
```

The above example will run/execute `do_stuff` if the exit status of `docker run` is zero which is a success.

You can add an `else` and `elif` clause in that

Or if you want to negate the exit status of the command.

```
if ! docker run container/myContainer:latest; then
  do_stuff
fi
```

The above example will run `do_stuff` if the exit status of `docker run` is anything but zero, e.g. 1 and going up, since the `!` negates.

If the command has some output and if does not have a silent/quite flag/option you can redirect it to `/dev/null`

```
if docker run container/myContainer:latest >/dev/null; then
  do_stuff
fi
```

- Should not output anything to `stdout`
- see `help test | grep -- '^[[:blank:]]*!'`
- In some cases if some output is still showing then that might be `stderr` which you can silent with `>/dev/null 2>&1` instead of just `>/dev/null`

Comment: will that be the exit code/output of docker run, or of the script that my container runs as its entrypoint?

Comment: I can't give you an answer because I don't  use docker, but as far as the shell is concern `0` is a success and the rest are a failure.